# One line of code converting JSON file to JSONP with .js extension

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

Trying to create an HTML5 banner (in Adobe Flash CC 2015 Canvas) and upload to Doubleclick Studio. It generates a tiny JSON file which DoubleClick won't allow.

This one line is the entire JSON file.  It looks to me like it's guiding the sprite placement for the images.

```
{"images": ["images/300x250_XF_1_atlas_.png"], "frames": [[220,0,159,270],[0,213,204,191],[206,272,196,191],[0,0,218,211]]}
```

DoubleClick Studio won't accept JSON files (see below).

> JSON: Files ending with .json are not allowed. (JSON files are not accepted by Studio for cross-domain reasons. JSON files must be rewritten as static JSONP file with a .js extension).
>   https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2672512<

Here's the function in the HTML code that loads the json file.

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};
    ss = ss||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadFile({src:"images/300x250_XF_1_atlas_.json", type:"spritesheet",   id:"300x250_XF_1_atlas_"}, true);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
```

Thank you very much for any time that you spend helping me. I'm an animator this is not my forte. I would imagine every banner I create will have a similar .JSON file output so hopefully the solution will work for all of them even if the number of images changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try doing the conversion manually with a text editor?

**This is JSON** (is what you've got)

filename: 300x250_XF_1_atlas_.json

```
{"images": ["images/300x250_XF_1_atlas_.png"], "frames": [[220,0,159,270],[0,213,204,191],[206,272,196,191],[0,0,218,211]]}
```

**This is JSONP** (just add `callback(`.....`);` to the json file)

filename: 300x250_XF_1_atlas_.js

```
callback({"images": ["images/300x250_XF_1_atlas_.png"], "frames": [[220,0,159,270],[0,213,204,191],[206,272,196,191],[0,0,218,211]]});
```

Answer (score 0):

So for future people trying to solve this, changing the publish settings inside the flash canvas dialogue to NOT combine all images into a sprite sheet will remove the JSON file and make it compatible with doubleclick.

Comment: But if you do that, the image files won't preload right?